# I want to create a directory whose name is stored in a variable using groovy

Tags: groovy, cmd

I want to create a folder named FUND whose value is stored in a variable 'r'.However the below code is creating a folder named $r and not FUND.

```
{
def r='FUND'
def proc= ['cmd', '/c','mkdir','$r']
Process process=proc.execute(null, new File('D:\app'));

process.waitForOrKill( 2000 )
println "Std Err: ${process.err.text}"
println "Std Out: ${process.in.text}" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a double quoted string (so-called `GString`) to allow for string interpolation in Groovy:

```
def r = 'FUND'
def proc = ['cmd', '/c', 'mkdir', "$r"]
```

Comment: It's working,Thanks. One quick question , if i want to change the drive let's say from c to d ,how can it be done using groovy? -@Robby

Comment: Windows doesn't have a concept of default drive. That is a DOS concept. CMD.exe emulates the concept for console programs.